# Missing _PublishedWebsites directory, global.asax and web.config

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, solution, msbuild-task

I used to write my own msbuild xml configuration file to compile and package my asp applications.
Usualy, calling the msbuild target on the solution generates a `_PublishedWebsites` directory in my `OutDir` directory.

```
<Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Init">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)" 
             Targets="Rebuild"
             Properties="OutDir=%(BuildDir.FullPath);
             Configuration=$(Configuration);
             Platform=$(BuildPlatform);
             DebugSymbols=$(DebugSymbols);
             DebugType=$(DebugType);
             AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=$(AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions)" />
</Target>
```

But for my last projet it does not.

All the code is in the OutDir and the `_PublishedWebsites` directory is not created... The `global.asax` and `web.config` files are also missing.

Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the classical _PublishedWebsite deployment directory adding the following lines to my .csproj web project file :

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Hope it helps!